# directing url through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I know that the code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is use to add www to the HTTP host every time a url is access without www.

similarly the code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Is use for posting every thing in the url to index.php in the value of the url variable. WITHOUT CHANGING THE URL LIKE IN THE FIRST EXAMPLE (which change the url from without www to with www).

What I want is little tricky.

I want if there is no www then the first example steps should be performed.

and if there is www, or any other text, for E.g. forum.site.com or blog.site.com or www.site.com then like in second example, it should silently direct to a folder of the same name.

eE.g. if it is www, it should rewrite to a folder `www/` folowed by the variable.

like 
a visitor type www.site.com
It should load the files from www/ folder and if visitor type
www.site.com/index.php?pid=1
then it should be rewritten to www/ folder along with the `index.php?pid=1` data

and the same should go for for any thing other than www. like for fourm.site.com/index.php?blah=blahBlah etc.

hope I m not confusing and am not breaking rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.+{3,}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.+\..+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The algorithm of the 2-nd rule is this:

1. I check, that the host consists of at least 3 parts, separated by dots. It's not an ideal solution, cause there are domains, naturally having 3 parts like .co.uk and .com.br. But, I assume, that you are using a domain of 2 parts.
2. So, if there are 3 parts, like: www.site.com, I put the 1-st part into %1 and 2-nd part into %2. So, %1 = 'www', %2 = 'site.com'.
3. Redirect everything to `http:://site.com/www/request`

If you have 3 parts domain, like site.co.uk, you can make a more complicated rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.+\..+\..+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite: `subdomain.site.co.uk` to `http://site.co.uk/subdomain/`

Comment: actually i will also use a 3 parts domain. so if you explain me how to make %1 %2 etc, then I will be very greatfull.

also tell me how to make the %1 part post in a variable. e.g. if `forum.site.com` is accessed, then how to rewrite it like `site.com/index.php?access=forum&otherRequest=value`

Comment: also your code changes the url in the address bar to www.site.com/www/

which i do not want. i want to silently load from site.com/www/ when any one access www.site.com.

Comment: @HezbullahShah I added the rule for 3 parts domain. %1, %2 are the references for the data in brackets. Just add another \..+ portion, which means [dot][something]

Comment: @HezbullahShah It shouldn't change the code in the address bar, as I don't R flag for the 2-nd RewriteRule. Very weird, didn't change for me.

Comment: Dear. See surani.com.pk     i did as you suggested for 3 parts.

Comment: i did as you suggested for 3 parts. It adds /www/ several times. Not just once. And says to be redirect loop.

Comment: While for two parts domain,  i noticed that it added /www/ only once.

Comment: @HezbullahShah I added the check for www redirect to avoid the possible loop. I saw, that it changes the url to sites.com/www, but I am not sure, that it's possible to keep it silent. Because we are using a new domain (even though it's a parent domain), and apache redirects to it.